# the meaning of the word 'bracketed'

Tags: word-meaning

> Icelanders practice **bracketed** indulgence. Everything in moderation,
>   they believe, including moderation. It’s perfectly acceptable to drink
>   yourself comatose on the weekend, but so much as sip a glass of
>   Chardonnay on a Tuesday night and you’re branded a lush.
>
> *The Geography of Bliss by Eric Weiner*

What is the meaning of '**bracketed**' here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't recognize this as standard usage, but going by context alone, I'd say it means something like "limited to a defined scope." Using their example: in Iceland, drinking alcohol (even to extremes) is acceptable or normal in certain conditions, yet taboo in others; therefore, the Icelanders' indulgence is "limited to a defined scope."

It seems that the American Heritage Dictionary (as cited [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bracketed)) could be taken to support such a usage:

> *tr.v.* **brack·et·ed, brack·et·ing, brack·ets**
>
> [...]
>
> **4.** To include or exclude by establishing specific boundaries.

(However, note that this is a verb, not an adjective.)

Comment: +1 "Bracketed" functionally meaning "an exception as aside or addendum -- "I drink [but only on the weeked]" ... "I practice moderation [but only in moderation]".

Comment: @TRomano That's a far better alternative :)

Answer (score 1):

If you bracket two or more things or ​people, you ​consider them to be ​similar or ​connected to each other: He's often bracketed with the ​romantic ​poets of this ​period ​although this does not ​reflect the ​range of his ​work.